# How to get the video path of the Replay Kit？

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, replaykit

Our app is a live app, do a video screen function, i use the replaykit. I want to customize the video preview, but i can not get the video of the recorded path.

Comment: Hey, did you get the solution for that ?

Comment: No solution was found.

Comment: Technically there is no path to the file, since Replay Kit doesn't "save" smapleBuffer as file format. It pool `CMSampleBuffer` from memory address and quickly release them to keep memory available. You can make deep copy of those sample buffers, create video file out of it and save it to device would be a solution.